# Pivot table in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this table as input

```
A        B       C
11001   1011    873824
11001   1012    2240
11002   1011    36792
11002   1012    557172
11003   1061    2970
```

I need this output using pivot

```
A           1011    1012    1061
11001       873824  2240
11002       36792   557172  
11003                       2970
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: Also, please provide your sample data in the following form: `declare @t table (A int, B int, C int);

insert  into @t
        (A, B, C)
values  (11001, 1011, 873824), 11001, 1012, 2240), etc...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Case` expression.

**Query**

```
select A,
max(case B when 1011 then C end) as [1011],
max(case B when 1012 then C end) as [1012],
max(case B when 1061 then C end) as [1061]
from your_table_name
group by A;
```

or you can use a dynamic sql query also.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select A, ' + stuff(
    (
        select distinct ',max(case B when ' + cast(B as varchar(50)) + ' 
               then C end) as [' + cast(B as varchar(50)) + ']'
        from your_table_name
        for xml path, type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    1, 1, ''
);

select @sql += ' from your_table_name group by A;'
execute (@sql);
```

Note : Assuming that your column datatype as `INT`.

**Result**

```
+=======+========+========+======+
| A     | 1011   | 1012   | 1061 |
+=======+========+========+=======+
| 11001 | 873824 | 2240   |      |
+-------+--------+--------+------+
| 11002 | 36792  | 557172 |      |
+-------+--------+--------+------+
| 11003 |        |        | 2970 |
+=======+========+========+======+
```

Comment: Column Datatype is String

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query

```
select A,[1011],[1012],[1061] from 
(select * from t)s
pivot
(max(C) for B in ([1011],[1012],[1061]))p
```

here's a link to demo fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93e1e/1

**Explanation:**

The above query uses the simple `PIVOT` syntax. Here all data from columns A, B, and C is selected in source set (aliased as s) and then pivoted on column B for values of column C.

**Helpful link:** Read more on msdn on PIVOT https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

**Dynamic SQL:**

```
--create table t (A int, B int, C int);
--insert into t values (11001,1011,873824)
--,(11001,1012,2240)
--,(11002,1011,36792)
--,(11002,1012,557172)
--,(11003,1061,2970);

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',[' + CAST(B AS NVARCHAR) +']' FROM t FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')

SET @query='select A,' + @cols + ' from '+
 '(select * from t)s '+
 'pivot '+
 '(max(C) for B in ('+@cols +'))p '

EXEC(@query)

--drop table t
```

Comment: I have Dynamic Data in B column

Comment: @J.Khan Updated my answer! Please do check.